# Case insensitive on command-line mode

Tags: vim

I often type these kind of things on command-line of vim because of the pressed shift from typing colon

```
:B1
:Enew
```

Then vim makes this warning something like this `Not an editor command: B1`.

Can I make this case insensitive? Or any better workaround?

Comment: there is no such option. because commands are case sensitive. You can define your own commands, beginning with Capt. letter. If you are looking for workaround, what I can think of is: in your vimrc create custom command `:B1, :Enew :...` and let them just simply exec the original vim built-in cmds. but it is not nice. do you want to "map" all built-in commands? it is quite a lot work. since you have to take care of the arguments, ranges stuffs in your command declaration.

Comment: In addition to @Kent suggestion, you could try to avoid the `shift` key, by mapping the `:` to some other key. But I believe the best would be to face the issue for some more time, until you get trained to release the key instead of working around.

Comment: Yes, I have `:` mapped to `;`. The `;` repeats `f` strokes, so I remapped that `;` to `-`.

Comment: @Kent Actually, I mapped `W`, `Q`, `Q!`, and `Wq`. 
@mMontu It's been several years after I started using vim but it's not getting better.
Maybe I should remap `:` to some other key as @NewWorld said.

Comment: @NewWorld `-` and `+` are very useful too, `-` goes to previous line and moves to the 1st non-empty char.

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround would be to use the abbreviations in command line mode.
And then you would either press space or press C-] to expand the abbreviation.

In your case:

```
:ca <buffer> Enew enew
:ca <buffer> B1 b1
```

Comment: I won't use this. say I want to replace word `TAB1<space>` to `TAB101<space>` in my buffer,  how would you do with the `ca`?

Comment: I agree it's not a clean solution. But I dont get your comment on the buffer. `:ca <buffer> TAB1 TAB101` will do it on the command line mode. Check `:help abbreviations` : I quote : "you can use it to automatically correct obvious spelling errors".

Comment: so what I meant is, when I typed `:%s/TAB1<space>/....` your `ca` will change the `B1` into `b1`, I cannot do the sub any longer!

Comment: got it, I agree it's pretty annoying. For words you use often and in **only** one case, I stick with the abbreviations, and go into the command window (Ctrl-f while typing command) to edit the command. Otherwise, I don't know another way than being careful. I asked on the vim user list how not to expand abbreviations, and the only way was to escape, change mode and go back to type the end of the word.